# How to report FAIL in my excel sheet when selenium automated testcase scenario fails?

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Scenario is :

1) Open browser.

2) Navigate to app URL.

3) Here come tricky part:

Almost most of the time driver is able to input to username and password using sendkeys() method.

But in rare case, driver is not able to perform operations and login page simply freeze.

Here is my script:

```
driver.findElement(XPATH).sendKeys(userName);
driver.findElement(XPATH).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(XPATH).click();

// waiting for landing page to load
  Thread.sleep(70000); 

  elib.setExcelData("DATA", 1, 4, "PASS");
```

**When everything works fine, it input PASS in my excel sheet.
Now, in-case of hangup of login page, how to input FAIL in the excel sheet?**

Note: I am selenium webriver with Java language.

Answer (score 1):

```
       driver.findElement(By.locator).sendkeys("username");

       driver.findElement(By.locator).sendkeys("password");

       driver.findElement(By.locator).click();

       //Instead of thread.wait use explicit wait to wait for the next page to load (timeout set 30 sec) increase or decrease timeout as per your needs

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        try{

        //any element on the homepage(page after login)

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

        }catch(Exception e)
            {//if this block executes then assume that your hang in the login page
              //you can also check if sendkeys has worked by getting the value from the username and password fields 
               driver.findElement(By.locator).getText(); or getAttribute('value');
               //then write fail into excel sheet
            }
       //continue with your test
```

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you need any further help

Comment: @Anand oh that's gr8... happy to be of help

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of why you need a test execution framework.  When your test has failed in this case, there will be some sort of exception thrown before the code ever gets to writing a result to the excel spreadsheet.  You basically need to use a tool (there are too many out there to list, but JUnit, TestNG are some basic ones) which will run your tests for you, then you can extract the pass/fail results from that tool into your spreadsheet (or use their reporting instead).

Comment: I am using TestNG framework. I want to feed the result of each step of a scenario in excel sheet.